# In EF Core when adding a many-to-many relationship, the related entities are updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

In EF Core, when I add entities in a many-to-many relationship, the relationships are created, but the added entities are also updated while there is no reason to do so (I don't modify these entities).

My models:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name  get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntitiesB> EntitiesB{ get; set; } 
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name  get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<EntitiesA> EntitiesA{ get; set; } 
}
```

My code

```
EntityA entityA = db.EntitiesA.Find(entityAId);
EntityB entityB = db.EntitiesB.Find(entityBId);

entityA.EntitiesB.Add(entityB);

db.SaveChanges();
```

The SQL generated request

```
UPDATE [EntityB] 
SET [Name] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;

INSERT INTO [EntitiesAEntitiesB] ([entityAId], [entityBId])
VALUES (@p2, @p3);
```

Why is EF Core generating an `UPDATE` query?

I also try this code :

```
EntityA entityA = db.EntitiesA.Find(entityAId);
EntityB entityB = db.EntitiesB.Find(entityBId);

db.Entry(entityB).State = EntityState.Detached;

entityA.EntitiesB.Add(entityB);

db.SaveChanges();
```

But I get the same result

Comment: Please provide [mre], including EF Core version information. Currently neither the provided classes compile, neither the sample code works (throws NRE because collections are null), and after fixing all that, there is no `UPDATE` command, just `INSERT`. Make sure there is no hidden code inside db context, for instance overriding `SaveChanges` and doing something behind the scenes.